# php website ran in an exe

Tags: php, html, compiler-construction, exe

I have built a website using php, jquery and mysql.it is running on the server now

Ive seen a Couple website to convert local php pages to exe files. 
But i am looking for a program that will allow me to run my website inside the exe
Is it possible to run a website on A Server in an Exe.

I was thinking of using an `hta` but it isn't much compatible with Internet Explorer. It changes the look and position of element on the website.

The reason is because I don't want people viewing the source of my website and some other reasons.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's in an exe or not. The only thing you can protect is people with access **to your server** not being able to read the source. Any one looking at the website would see the HTML any way, as that's the way the browser renders the page. Whatever you think you're doing, just don't.

Comment: when someone goes to your website, the page that gets rendered has your html/js/css/etc... you're not able to get around this... 

If you're interested in someone not seeing your 'php' code on your server, then you'd have to create 'resources' for an .exe handle the webpage tcp requests yourself (much bigger deal and honestly not really worth it...

Comment: So many people spend so much time worrying about their PHP code being stolen. The thing is, 99.999% of that code isn't worth stealing. And even if it is worth stealing, none of the methods of "hiding" code actually work. Even an exe file can be disassembled. The only way to really hide code is to have it on a remote server. If it's local, then a determined user will be able to read it, no matter what you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NuSphere has a product that can do what you are looking for. It is called PhpDock. I have used it and it performs as advertised. It comes with a web server built into it, so all you have to do is distribute the .exe to the user and they will then be able to run your web application as a native application.

[NuSphere PhpDock Product Page](http://www.nusphere.com/products/phpdock.htm)